# Pandas take only year out of full date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a column of `start_year` in which I save values only by years.
Some of the values look like date for example : `27 July 1947`

I want to transfer those into year : `27 July 1947 -> 1947` using pandas

I have tried this code without succses, (months is array contain all months):

```
for month in months:
        mnt = df[df["start_year"].str.contains(month)]["start_year"].to_list()
        only_year = [year.split(" ")[2] for year in mnt]
        df.replace(mnt, only_year, inplace=True)
```

I also have strings such as `123 BC` or `23`, for example. Can I run the df['start_year'].str[-4:] only on specific indexes?

Comment: If it's a string `df['start_year'].str[-4:]` or `df['start_year'].dt.year` if it's datetime?

Comment: @HenryEcker I've shold have mentioned I also have strings such as 123 BC or 23 for example, Can I run the df['start_year'].str[-4:] only on specific indexes?

Comment: Yes you should edit your question to include a sample frame that contains realistic data for your problem so that it can be solved completely.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to convert the column 'start_year' to Pandas datetime, and then extract only the year portion:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'start_year': ['2020', '27 July 1947', '1990', '123 BC', '23'],
'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
})

def extract_year(x):
    try:
        return pd.to_datetime(x).year
    except:
        return x

df['year'] = df['start_year'].apply(lambda x: extract_year(x))
```

Output

```
     start_year name    year
0          2020    A    2020
1  27 July 1947    B    1947
2          1990    C    1990
3        123 BC    D  123 BC
4            23    E      23
```

Comment: This won't work for the extended values in the comments `'123 BC'` or `'23'`

Comment: How about define your own function to extract the year, see edited codes above

Comment: I've updated the codes to keep the string dates such as "123 BC" and "23 AD", does this work for you?